# Serialize xml in a specific format in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a class like so:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class UIColor
{
    public UIColor()
    {
    }

    public UIColor(double red, double green, double blue, double alpha)
    {
        r = (float)red;
        g = (float)green;
        b = (float)blue;
        a = (float)alpha;
    }

    public UIColor(double white, double alpha)
    {
        r = (float)white;
        g = (float)white;
        b = (float)white;
        a = (float)alpha;

    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("r", typeof(float))]
    public float r
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("g", typeof(float))]
    public float g
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("b", typeof(float))]
    public float b
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("alpha", typeof(float))]
    public float a
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And many instances of it in a class like so:

```
class Colors
{
[XmlElement("Col1")]
  UIColor Col1;
[XmlElement("Col2")]
  UIColor Col2;
  //etc etc
}
```

What I'd like to do is serialize out the class Colors into xml in the following format:

```
<Color name="Col1" r="1" g="1" b="1" alpha="1"/>
<Color name="Col2" r="2" g="2" b="2" alpha="2"/>
```

Currently the way it serializes out is like:

```
<Col1>
<r>1</r>
//etc etc
```

Comment: You may want to look at [XMLAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: When using XmlAttribute I got errors about using them on primitive types

Comment: You need to remove the parameters `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute` you will also need to define and remove schema details.

Answer (score 2):

Your original class should look like:

```
[System.Serializable]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("Color")]
public class UIColor
{
    public UIColor()
    {
        name = "Col1"
    }

    public UIColor(double red, double green, double blue, double alpha)
    {
        r = (float)red;
        g = (float)green;
        b = (float)blue;
        a = (float)alpha;
        name = "Col1";
    }

    public UIColor(double white, double alpha)
    {
        r = (float)white;
        g = (float)white;
        b = (float)white;
        a = (float)alpha;
        name = "Col1";
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute]
    public string name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute]
    public float r
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute]
    public float g
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute]
    public float b
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("alpha")]
    public float a
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And the serialization code:

```
using (System.IO.TextWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\test.xml"))
{
      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xml = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(UIColor));
      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces namspace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
      namespace.Add("", "");
      xml.Serialize(writer, new UIColor(), namespace);
}
```

And the out XML will produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Color name="Col1" r="0" g="0" b="0" alpha="0" />
```